# Find number of rows with particular match to a set of numbers

Tags: php

I have a tricky question which I can not find the answer to myself. I am using web host with  MySQL v5.0.92-50-log and PHP v5.2.17.

I have a table, where in each row there are 6 numbers in separate columns and some more columns - name, etc.

There are 2 things I know how to do:

1.How to loop through all rows and check for matches to a particular set of numbers as follow:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die();
$matchValues = array(1,2,3);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$counter = 0;
foreach($matchValues as $value)
{
    if(in_array($value, $row))
    {
        $counter++;
    }
}
```

Then I can output the "name" field and the "counter" result for it (1 match, 2 matches or 3).

2.I know how to find the number of rows as follow:

`$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE status='Approved'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);`

The trick is how to combine them. I need to do the search as per 1, then output the name field and number of matches and I need to know how many rows have 1 match, how many rows have 2 and how many rows have 3.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In order to combine both of these tasks, simply use `SELECT * FROM $tablename` and then have a counter called `$approved_cntr` which would accumulate as you go through the results, checking if `$row['status'] == 'Approved'`. This will give you an equivalent value for the number of approved status rows.

Also, it's in your best interests to look into `mysqli` or `mysql_PDO` libraries, as the `mysql_*` functions that you appear to be using are deprecated.

**MySQL (PDO) Reference**: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

**mysqli Reference**: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php